# Sound feedback when you type on keyboard (Windows, like KeyClick)

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard

I'm searching for an application like "[KeyClick](http://sustworks.com/site/prod_keyclick_overview.HTML)". That one is for OS X, I need one for Microsoft Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the free product [Home Typist](http://www.colorpilot.com/home-typist.html) :

> Home Typist adds typewriter sounds to
>   your computer keyboard. The program is
>   useful for home typists. At every
>   touch of the keyboard there is the new
>   sound, which makes the process of
>   typing more interesting, amuses and
>   reduces stress and helps to produce
>   rhythmic typing.

Another one is [Qwertick](http://www.nattyware.com/qwertick.php) :

> It adds a sound feedback to your
>   keyboard, a touch of an old typewriter
>   that stimulates creativity.

If you want to hear sounds other than Typewriter ‘tick tick’, then have a look at [Clickey utility](http://www.grc.com/freeware/clickey.htm) that has 26 different sounds for different key strokes on computer keyboard.

Comment: Well.. it is something, but if I type fast, the sound becomes really strange.

Comment: Like... if I type too fast, they don't overlap, but sound A stops and B starts. That's just weird. Tried their commercial product, but it have the same problem. :/

Comment: It "sounds" logical to me that the new key overrides the old. Otherwise the sound could lag far behind the typist, especially if some of the sounds are long-playing.

Comment: But it's just so strange. I mean.. try it out. I don't care if the sounds are short, but it's a bit annoying ^^".

Comment: I added a couple of more products (I didn't really believe there would be 3 such). I take no responsibility for any of them.